# how to use either email or login in Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic with my Ruby on Rails App. I would like user to enter either user name or password in one field to authenticate. How do I do this with Authlogic?

I know I can switch to using email:

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :email
  end
```

I was sure if I can tell Authlogic to use either.

Cheers,

Tam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331705/cant-put-email-address-field-on-login-form-authlogic).